# How do I connect to an external MongoDB Collection in a Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

By default the Meteor app has access to collections in a database called meteor, but I would like to connect to a collection contained in a different database.

Looking around, I found some snippets which try to do the following:

```
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/meteor';
var oplogUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/local';

var remoteDriver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(mongoUrl, {
    oplogUrl: oplogUrl,
});

var remoteCollection = new Mongo.Collection('extract', {
    _driver: remoteDriver,
});
```

But doing so my app is crashing giving the following error:

```
> Exited with code: 8
? (STDERR)
? (STDERR) /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3.ems6rm++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
? (STDERR)                          throw(ex);
? (STDERR)                                ^
? (STDERR) Error: $MONGO_OPLOG_URL must be set to the 'local' database of a Mongo replica set
? (STDERR)     at Error (<anonymous>)
? (STDERR)     at OplogHandle._startTailing (packages/mongo/oplog_tailing.js:216:13)
? (STDERR)     at new OplogHandle (packages/mongo/oplog_tailing.js:76:8)
? (STDERR)     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:216:25)
? (STDERR)     at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.collections.job_extract.js (collections/job_extract.js:10:20)
? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
? (STDERR)     at /Users/test/app_meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:1453:1
? (STDERR)     at /Users/test/app_meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:291:10
? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/arj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3.ems6rm++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
? (STDERR)     at /Users/test/app_meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

Comment: It means that your `oplogUrl` does not point to a valid MongoDB oplog source. Did you set one up?

Comment: What is a MongoDB oplog ? Do I have to set it up myself ? As there is already a MongoDB server running on 27018, shouldn't it already have a oplog running ?

Comment: You don't have to use oplog (the format used by MongoDB for representing operations and used in replica sets), but the alternative to it is using poll-and-diff. You can read more about it [here](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-mongodb-replica-set-for-oplog-tailing). You can run your DB as a single-node replica set, but configuring it depends on your MongoDB version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through running command inside an meteor app
export MONGO_URL=URL.
Then your app will be connected to the URL database.

Comment: I do not want to change the complete database to a remote database, I want my meteor app runs on it's proper database and on addition I want to access a collection from the remote database.